# Confidence level using unknown median

Tags: probability, statistics, median

This is a general question.

Lets say we are giving a sample space n.

The sample space has an **unknown median**

The order statistics of each person, $**X_{i}**$ in sample space is measured (lets say we measure their weights)

How am I supposed to find the level of confidence in (%) for $X_{48}$ < MEDIAN < X_{62} ?

Many thanks.

Comment: http://www.milefoot.com/math/stat/ci-medians.htm

Comment: Many thanks! Answered my question